# exe is giving an error while execution, after create exe from auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I have created exe using auto-py-to-exe, after exe created I tried to run exe so i got an error like "No package metadata was found for pikepdf"

I reinstalled the pikepdf and I also downloaded the package from github but still not solved that error
I have created exe using auto-py-to-exe, after exe created I tried to run exe so i got an error like "No package metadata was found for pikepdf"
Kindly, help me solve an error.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/1793

I got the answer here.

Add this to your main.py before creating exe file.

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from importlib import metadata
else:
    from importlib_metadata import metadata


_pikepdf_version = tuple(
    [int(i) for i in metadata.version("pikepdf").split(".")[:2]]
)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76239468/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).